# Stop custom setInterval() function similar to clearInterval() using return variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a custom setInterval function that can modify the interval as it runs. I would like to be able to return a variable that the caller can modify later on. Similar to how clearInterval() works.

**Custom Set Interval Function**

```
customSetInterval(callback, interval) {
  let stop = false;
  this.startInterval(callback, interval, stop);
  return stop;
}

startInterval(callback, interval, stop) {
  if (stop) {
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
    interval += 100;
    this.startInterval(callback, interval, stop);
  }, interval);
}
```

My current implementation doesn't work because I'm simply returning the value. Not the variable itself. Is it possible to do something like this in JS?

**Example Execution**

```
let stop = this.devicewise.customSetInterval(() => {
  console.log('HELLO!');
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('stopping!');
  stop = true;
}, 5000);
```

If this is not possible I plan on creating a boolean hashmap that I add to every time I start. Then create a customClearInterval function to modify that hashmap.

Comment: can you wrap `stop` in an object and pass around?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the returned variable?

Comment: @jom Have an id to clear the interval like `clearInterval` I think.

Comment: @jom correct. I want to have clearInterval happen with a variable. It would be much more convenient than having to manage all the running intervals in a map.

Comment: @AustenStone OK, so why not setting the initialized id in a class constructor? This should be accessible for clearing at a later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you wanted a one-time execution with the callback, maybe something like that:

```
class CustomInterval {
    constructor() {
        this.id = -1;
    }

    start(callback, interval) {
        console.log(`executing callback in ${interval}ms`);

        this.id = setTimeout(() => {
            callback();
            console.log('callback fired');
        }, interval);
    }

    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.id);
        console.log('stopped');
    }
}

// ...
let j = new CustomInterval();

j.start(() => {
    // do stuff here
}, 5000);

// after some other operations, you decided to cancel the above delayed execution
// no problem.
j.stop();
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain why? That definitely worked for me and should address the OP's problem.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something. If you think my post is unhelpful, please state the reason.

Comment: I like your answer. ++jom